# generate array with logic calculate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd intend to generate an array of (64,6), which consist of binary bit array of each number (0 to 63)

I've figured out the logic as below:

```
[int(x) for x in bin(63)[2:]]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[int(x) for x in bin(60)[2:]]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[int(x) for x in bin(3)[2:]]
[1, 1]
```

my expect output is something like this:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,1],
...
[1,1,1,1,1,0],
[1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

however, following codes don't work

```
x = np.arange(0,64)
[int(i) for i in bin(x)[2:]]
```

Comment: What is the error or problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to generate all sequences of binary digits from `0` up to `64`. In this case, you really have two loops going on, so you need two list comprehensions.

```
x = np.arange(0, 64)
[ [int(i) for i in bin(y)[2:]] for y in x ]
```

If you want the values padded so that they're all of the same length, you can pad the resulting list elements yourself.

```
x = np.arange(0, 64)
a = [ [int(i) for i in bin(y)[2:]] for y in x ]
list(map(lambda x: [0] * (6 - len(x)) + x, a))
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use `for` loop and string to list conversion:

```
for i in range(64):
    s = str(bin(i))[2:] # create binary value, convert to string and remove initial '0b'
    while len(s) < 6:   # add leading 0s if needed
        s = "0"+s
    lst = list(s)       # convert to list
    lst = list(map(lambda x: int(x), lst))  # convert each element from string to integer
    print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
...
...
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```